# How to output file upload date (of a file field) in a JSON-view?

Tags: views, files, datetime

I have rest_export view to generate json output of nodes.
I'm trying to output a the upload date of files in a multivalue filefield, but can't find a solution.
I tried to use the "rewrite results" option of the filefield in the view using twig as follows:

{% for item in field_myfiles %}
{{ item.entity.timestamp|date("Y-m-d H:i:s") }}
{% endfor %}

But it just does not work. Any hints how to achieve this?